# How can I suppress the stacktraces and html in Wicket development mode

Tags: logging, wicket

Usually the first line in the error message is sufficient in solving the problem so I do not want to pollute my console in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

You can subclass WebRequestCycle and override newRequestCycle in your WebApplication class. In WebRequestCycle you can handle RuntimeExceptions in any manner. There's a good explanation with code samples [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/error-pages-and-feedback-messages.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or in MyApp#init() set:
getExceptionSettings().setUnexpectedExceptionDisplay(
                    IExceptionSettings.SHOW_INTERNAL_ERROR_PAGE);

This will show the configured "error 500" page and log the exception in the server log files